# Render text from controller to view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller from which I want to render text to /views/test/index.html.erb:

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if testStuff() do
      <render text to view>
    end
  end

  private 
  testStuff()
    return true
  end
end
```

What is the easiest way to do this?
Thanks for an answer!

Comment: do you render to which page?

Comment: Use variables like @test to show in index page

Comment: No need to render.Because same method and view

Comment: I didn't want to assign variables, is there another way?

Comment: I dont get the question;  /views/test/index.html.erb is automatically rendered after the index action, so you can just put text in that file?

Comment: You should probably go through a basic [Ruby tut. and Rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After executing the method index of the controller rails will try to load a view with name index.html.erb (or any other template you use).
You may declare a member in index and that member will be available to the view, ex:

```
def index
  @text = "Hello world!"
end
```

Then in your view:

```
...
<span><%= @text %></span>
...
```

If your @text variable has html you trust then use @text.html_safe in your view.

Answer (score 0):

try to assign text into a Instance Variable. Like:

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if testStuff() do
      @text = "Text what you want to render"
    end
  end
```

**at view:**

```
<%= @text %>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the current solution, I was wondering if there's another way

Comment: ok, could you please tell me why do you need another way to implement that? It's a most conventional way to render text to view in RoR. Thanks.

Comment: I was just wondering if there' another way I might like. Also I was not sure if this is the best way, apparently it is:-)

Answer (score 0):

You can render as json like this

```
def index
    if testStuff() do
     @category_lists = CategoryList.get_categories(current_user.id)

     respond_to do |format|
       format.html # index.html.erb
       format.json { render json: @category_lists }
     end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not good, you can move you test to the view:

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :is_test?      

  def index
  end

  private 

  def is_test?
    return true
  end
end
```

And then in view:

```
<% if is_test? %>
  <span>Some text here</span>
<% end %>
```